# Could I use 'set_password' method in DRF without AbstractUser in my model?

Tags: python, oop, django-rest-framework

I'm newbiew with DRF (and programming) and a big problem is with me.

I have this Model:

```
class Player (models.Model):

    user_id         = models.UUIDField (primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, blank=True)
    username        = models.CharField (max_length=30, unique=True, null=False)
    email           = models.EmailField (max_length=50, unique=True, null=False)
    password        = models.CharField (max_length=100, null=True)
    is_validated    = models.BooleanField (default=False)
    created         = models.DateField (auto_now_add=True)
    updated         = models.DateField (auto_now=True)
    
    class Meta:

        verbose_name = 'player'
        verbose_name_plural = 'players'
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
        'username'
    ]

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.username
```

And this Serializer:

```
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = Player(
            email = validated_data["email"],
            username = validated_data["username"]
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data["password"])
        user.save()
        return user

    def validate_password (self, value):
        if len (value) < 8 or len (value) > 30:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Password length must be between 8 and 30.')
        return value
```

When I create a new player, always have the same issue:
*'Player' object has no attribute 'set_password'*

How could I use 'set_password' without import AbstractUser?

I've tried extending the User model with OnetoOnelink but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you should do here is write a python function that saves a player's password in the `models.py` file, then instead of calling `set_password` you can call the function you've created.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i think the issue here is that the `Player` model doesn't have a defined method called set_password, unlike the defualt django `User` model and `AbstractUser` that have that method inbuilt.

You have to define a custom `set_passowrd` method

Comment: def set_password(self, password):
        self.password = password
        return password

Something like this?